# ASP style render - differences

Tags: asp.net

I read examples, but I don't understand what is different between:

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and

```
 <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Style/style") %>
```

why use second example?
Thanks!

Comment: The second is a style bundle - there you can minify contained css and Combine them into one file.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a normal HTML css include link.

The second is part of the System.Web.Optimization bundling package. You can set up bundles to combine multiple stylesheets into a single stylesheet (Note: In debug mode it will still show multiple stylesheets). This reduces the number of trips your page makes back and forth to the server and should speed up page load times.

Here's a [tutorial article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) from the ASP.net site.